# Documentation on "Analyzer errors" codes?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2

As noted [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00vp0000002r001272), when you receive an error of the form

```
001272 : Analyzer errors were encountered (codes = <value>).
```

this means that the attempt to stage and publish a service failed.

The tool provides a set of codes in the error message, but the documentation I linked to only tells you to fire up an ArcGIS Desktop tool to find out the problem. Instead, I would prefer to use the code to look up what the error is; this would be especially helpful to me since the publish is happening automatically in Python via arcpy.

Is there a resource that tells us what the codes mean?

I am using 10.2 at the moment and will soon be upgrading to 10.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that the documentation of the error codes can be found in the [Technical guide for map services](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/map/publish-map-services/drawing-behaviors-of-the-map-service.htm). Specifically, the documentation is in the [Prepare window messages](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/map/publish-map-services/00001-data-frame-does-not-have-layers.htm) section. The codes in that list are padded with leading zeros, but the numbers themselves match up.

Comment: The guide has since been updated: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/publish-map-services/00001-data-frame-does-not-have-layers.htm. I haven't seen something similar for Pro, however.

Answer (score 0):

When I got the error message 001272 : Analyzer errors were encountered (codes = 3), I tried to use a new .mxd as some suggested.
Through trial and error the problem was rectified by decreasing the data path (long folder names/ data folders too deep) simply by copying my data to a higher folder in the data tree. If that makes sense.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. We are not a discussion forum; instead we use a Focused question/Best answer model. While this Answer addresses the specific error code mentioned, the Question itself is about a reference to all error codes, which this does not address.